# Why won't sed remove my NULLs? (OS X)

Tags: macos, shell, sed

can someone tell me why sed won't remove my NULLs?

this is on OS X

```
$ printf '123\x00456' | sed 's/\x00/Z/g' | hexdump 
0000000 31 32 33 00 34 35 36 0a
```

this doesn't work either:

```
$ printf '123'$(echo "\000")'456' | sed 's/'$(echo "\000")'/Z/g' | hexdump 
0000000 31 32 33 00 34 35 36 0a
```

Comment: yes, you have GNU sed. 

Macs have Free BSD sed

Thanks for confirming, tho!

Comment: For replacing a single character with another single character, the `tr` command is better. `printf '123\x00456' | tr '\0' Z | hexdump`

Comment: that's a really good point, but I am actually trying to remove nulls. i put the 'Z' in there so as not to confuse people. what I really want is: printf '123\x00456' | sed 's/\x00//g' | hexdump

Comment: `tr` is still good! `-d` option for delete: `printf '123\x00456' | tr -d '\0' | hexdump` - oh I see that an answer has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For deleting a single character or translating a single character to a single other character (not including multibyte characters), `tr` can do it, and unlike sed it supports all characters, including NULs, in all versions of unix since the beginning.

For translating:

```
tr '\0' Z
```

And for deleting:

```
tr -d '\0'
```